# NSUserdefaults from TVTopShelfProvider conformed class: get nil

Tags: nsuserdefaults, tvos, topshelf

I'm trying to get UserDefaults from ServiceProvider -  the Top Shelf extension class and get nil.

```
class ServiceProvider: NSObject, TVTopShelfProvider {
....

   var topShelfItems: [TVContentItem] {
   ....
   item!.title = String(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("title"))
```

At the same time when AppDelegate launches i can get the value.
Is there any other way to save user-related data and then get this data from ServiceProvider?

Answer (score 2):

In iOS and tvOS extensions run in their own process/sandbox and do not inherently have access to the data of the application or other extensions.  The solution to this is to setup an app group for the extension and the app, which allows you to access a shared container in the file system on the device (including a shared `NSUserDefaults` instance).  You can read more about it in the [Sharing Data with Your Containing App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW6) part of the [Handling Common Scenarios](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1) chapter in the [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG).